# Custom control made of radio buttons not checking radio button if data binding is same as default

Tags: wpf, data-binding, entity-framework-4, custom-controls

I created a custom control, which is simply three radio buttons, and an `Answer` property of type `string` that can be one of `"Yes"`, `"No"`, or `"N/A"`. Clicking the radio buttons changes the `Answer` property, or changing the `Answer` property should change which radio button is selected. `Answer` is implemented as a DependancyProperty so I can perform data binding with it (the source is a property of an EF4 entity).

It all works well and good, except in one particular situation - when the value of the column in the database matches the default specified in the `DependencyProperty.Register()` call. In this case, the control is displayed without *any* radio button checked!

I've turned off the option for the debugger to step over property setters, and I know that `SetChecks`() is being called and supposedly setting the `IsChecked` property of the radio button to true.

If I change the default of the property, that becomes the value that is not checked... `MyId` was put in place just to identify the specific control I'm looking at in the debugger, since I have multiple of these controls in my view.

First the `.cs` code:

```
public partial class YesNoNotApplicableRadio : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public string MyId {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnswerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Answer",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(YesNoNotApplicableRadio),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("N/A",
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(AnswerPropertyChanged),
            new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceAnswer)
            ),
        new ValidateValueCallback(ValidateAnswer)
        );

    public static bool ValidateAnswer(Object value) {
        string s = value as string;
        if (s == null)
            return true;
        s = s.Trim().ToUpper();
        if (s.Equals("YES") || s.Equals("NO") || s.Equals("N/A") || s.Equals(""))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void AnswerPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        YesNoNotApplicableRadio o = d as YesNoNotApplicableRadio;
        string val = (string)e.NewValue;
        SetChecks(o, val.Trim().ToUpper());
    }

    private static void SetChecks(YesNoNotApplicableRadio selector, string val) {
        selector.YesRadio.IsChecked = false;
        selector.NoRadio.IsChecked = false;
        selector.NaRadio.IsChecked = false;
        if (val.Equals("YES"))
            selector.YesRadio.IsChecked = true;
        else if (val.Equals("NO"))
            selector.NoRadio.IsChecked = true;
        else if (val.Equals("N/A") || val.Equals(""))
            selector.NaRadio.IsChecked = true;
    }

    private void Radio_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        if ((bool)YesRadio.IsChecked)
            Answer = "Yes";
        else if ((bool)NoRadio.IsChecked)
            Answer = "No";
        else
            Answer = "N/A";
    }

    public static Object CoerceAnswer(DependencyObject d, Object baseValue) {
        YesNoNotApplicableRadio o = (YesNoNotApplicableRadio)d;
        string s = baseValue as string;
        if (s == null)
            return ("N/A");
        else
            return (s);
    }

    public string Answer {
        get { return ((string)GetValue(AnswerProperty)); }
        set { SetValue(AnswerProperty, value); NotifyPropertyChanged("Answer"); }
    }

    public YesNoNotApplicableRadio() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Guid groupGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        YesRadio.GroupName = groupGuid.ToString();
        NoRadio.GroupName = groupGuid.ToString();
        NaRadio.GroupName = groupGuid.ToString();

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Here is the `.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RovingAuditEntry.Controls.YesNoNotApplicableRadio"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="130">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
        <RadioButton Content="Yes" Height="16" Name="YesRadio" Click="Radio_Click" />
        <RadioButton Content="No" Height="16" Name="NoRadio" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="Radio_Click" />
        <RadioButton Content="N/A" Height="16" Name="NaRadio" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="Radio_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution, although it's probably not the right one. Valid inputs to the control are `null`, an empty string, `"Yes"`, `"No"`, and `"N/A"` (with any capitalization). My coerce function will transform `null` and empty string to `"N/A"`. By changing the default value passed to the `Register()` function from `"N/A"` to `""`, it now works.

Still looking for a better answer, but in the absence of one, I'll accept my own.